# Is it safe to edit my existing ubuntu partition with an ubuntu dvd

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, live-cd

I am increasing my Ubuntu partition size (dual booting windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04). Shrinking the Windows partition did not go well (but works now; in other question). So i am wondering if it is safe to increase the partition size using a Ubuntu live dvd.

Answer (score 7):

Define safe. *Nothing* is 100% safe, especially not when fiddling with your partition table. You should always make a backup before attempting to resize partitions. The operation involves making changes to the disk so it is possible that data will be lost.

Having said that, I must admit that I've done this many, many times over the years and have never had any problems. So yes, I'd say it's "safe". That doesn't mean that there is no possibility of failure though.

You can think of this like routine surgery. On the one hand it's routine, so it's safe; on the other hand, it's surgery and somebody will be cutting into you using a sharp object, so it's dangerous.

Bottom line: go ahead and do it, but make a backup first, just in case.

Comment: I dont have anything "important" on my **Ubuntu partition**.  Backup: with what software, and what to back up (i only have about 50-60 GB of discs). I have never made a backup before as installing ubuntu, resizing windows 10: everything went (almost) fine.

Comment: @PyotrK Backups are for when everything doesn't go fine. Since we can't tell the future, we backup. Power failures, hardware failures, etc. can ruin your day. Regarding backup strategies: http://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc

Answer (score 2):

I'll echo what others have said... backup backup backup.

Changing Windows partitions should always be done inside of Windows. To extend, just use Disk Management. To shrink, defrag first, then use Disk Management.

Assuming that you haven't done any damage after a problematic Windows partition resize, running gparted from the Ubuntu Live DVD is the way to go to resize the Ubuntu partition. If you need to resize, **DON'T** change the **FRONT/LEFT** of the Ubuntu partition, change the **REAR/RIGHT**. If you can't change the **REAR/RIGHT**, then **MOVE** the partition **left**, then resize the **REAR/RIGHT**.

Cheers, Al

Comment: Okay, so my windows partition is in front of the Ubuntu partition, and between is  200 **GiB** (do not confuse with GB) of unallocated space. Moving the partition to the left and resize to the right does basically the same as resizing to the left.

Comment: **Try it. Report back.** I think the difference is slight, but I'd rather do the partition resize and move data left at the same time, instead of having gparted change the partition size and then come back to move the data (which now appears in the middle of the new larger partition). I could be wrong about the internal workings of gparted, but my perception is that resizing the left side of a partition can cause problems. Cheers, Al

Comment: Think it would be easier to just reinstall Ubuntu, I don't have any files that i care about there.

Comment: Since you can reinstall Ubuntu, go ahead and just try the left-side partition resize and let us know if it works... before reinstalling Ubuntu. Inquiring minds want to know. Cheers, Al

Comment: Reinstalling automatically resizes and moves the partition, which is kind of weird as it uses any unallocated space, without asking for how big you want the partition to be. It boots, everything seems fine. I have not checked if windows for some random reason won't boot. This seems more reliable than resizing and moving partitions with gparted. I don't know if restoring from a backup is possible.

Answer (score 1):

It is as safe as editing partitions in Windows. If you know (exactly) what you're doing, it is 'safe'. If in doubt, just search on Youtube, there are many examples there. And make backups before attempting anything, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling Ubuntu automatically uses free space. It seems more reliable and safer than doing it by yourself. If possible, restore data from a backup.